# "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException" Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I was building a project that sends e-mails from my website to an account using SMTP with the Asp.NET Framework with MVC, but, when I try to send the e-mail it catches the next exception

> *The SMTP server requires a secure connection, or the client did not authenticate. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required*

This is the code inside the try

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.From = new MailAddress("myemailfortesting@gmail.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(contact.Email));
message.Subject = "Test";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "Name:" + contact.Name+ "Message:" + contact.Text;

using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
{
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemailfortesting@gmail.com", "p455w0rD");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

The connection string in Views/Share/Web.config

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="myemailfortesting@gmail.com">
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myemailfortesting@gmail.com" password="p455w0rD" defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="true"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I've already turn on the **Less secure apps** in my destination Google account.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you try to change the port to 465, as documented by google [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/protocols-pop3-smtp-imap/#What_is_SMTP_and_which_are_the_default_SMTP_ports)

Comment: Oh no.. Port 587 works, but what I had to do was to go to gmail.com, click "Manage Your Google Account" -> "Security issues found" web part and confirm that it was me who tried to access from a less secure app.. Oh my..